# How to pass the variable from Python and receive it in PHP

Tags: python, php, ajax, post, file-upload

**Background**

I see similar questions in Stack Overflow, but I didn't get the answer I want. I am trying to develop a project which contains a upload page where users upload the image to it which is saved on server.

Server runs the Machine learning algorithm to detect the objects and send the detected object back to the server and displays in same webpage (upload page).

**What I did**

Currently I finished the upload page and Python ML code.

I need to send the detected objects from Python back to the PHP server, for that I user Python request module and successfully post the message to the server.

```
//obj detection code here
detected_obj= {"value": "This image contains car cycle")}     // Have to send this data
import requests
url = "http://localhost/index.php"
r = requests.post(url, data=detected_obj)
print(r.text)                               // I got the entire html code of the index.php
```

But in PHP, I can't able to get the response back.

```
//PHP code
//rest of the file upload code
<?php
$value = $_POST["value"];
echo $value;
?>
```

**What I want**

I think I made some mistake in PHP code, I'm new to PHP. How can I get the value from Python request and update in PHP?

*i.e PHP has to wait for any POST message and when it received it has to print the posted data in the webpage.*

I searched in internet, where they get the post message from the form and validate it using isset() method and print the response. In my case I had no form, PHP listens for any post message, once it receives, it has to print the message in the same page.

On internet, I found that it can be done by ajax, but I didn't know how to do this and how it fits in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you didn't set up PHP server.

First of all, you need your http://localhost/index.php to work. When your PHP code will work then try to post message from Python.

You can find info about setting up PHP on the server side here: https://www.php.net/manual/install.php

Comment: Thanks for the response, but my I already set up the PHP server and it is running. And I able to access http://localhost/index.php

Comment: And what you see on that page? What this page return to you when you send POST request by Postman or other tool for testing REST?